# I spotted a misspelled tag. Can it be edited or does it have to be burninated?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The OP of a recent question misspelled their new tag [kate-and-leopald](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kate-and-leopald) but of course it should be [kate-and-leopold](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kate-and-leopold). I nearly retagged it but at the last minute realized a mod might be able to rename it.

Comment: Changed it. Did it on mobile let me know if I mucked it up at all! Note if the system lets you when it’s only on a couple of questions and no usage guidance just remove the tag and create the new one by editing the posts yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know the specific number of questions  below which the tag will self-burninate if you unlink it?

Comment: You realize, of course, whether or not that's the way it really works, I just HAD to use the term "self-burninate".

Comment: Tags will be deleted by the daily job when they don’t exist on any question.

Answer (score 3):

This is already fixed, but for completeness and posterity, here are the options to rename a misspelled tag:

- **Edit each post manually**. Hopefully a misspelled tag wouldn't survive long enough to be used on many questions, so this should be a feasible task. However, if the correct spelling is very close to the existing one, the system may not let you create a tag that's "too similar", and you may need mod assistance.
- **Mod-merge the tag.** This automatically renames the tag and replaces it on all posts having that tag, but it can only be done by a diamond mod. (The process is the same as for merging a tag into another one: as a mod, you go to the page for the existing tag, click on the "Merge" button next to "Synonyms", and type in the new desired name for the tag.

There is **no need to burninate** a tag that's been removed from all questions; it will automatically disappear from the system within 24 hours anyway. (If desired, the mod-merge process mentioned above can also add a synonym so that anyone typing the misspelled tag name will automatically get the new tag name. This is a checkbox option on the mod merge page, and it may be desirable for very common misspellings.)